# Access "header" in Azure databricks notebook

Tags: python, azure, exception, jupyter-notebook, databricks

my scenario is:
I am running a databricks notebook from within another notebook via:
`dbutils.notebooks.run(...)`

This notebook might fail and raise an Py4JJavaError.
My question is:
How do access the header of the errors traceback, therefore this line which I can toggle to show the full traceback:

```
com.databricks.WorkflowException: com.databricks.NotebookExecutionException: FAILED
```

[image: 1]

I know I can except the Py4JJavaError, but cannot find (an) attribute(s) containing the information of this line.

Best,
Karl

Comment: Have you considered [try](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) statement?

Comment: Hi, 
yes so I know and I do except the Py4JJavaError via try/except. But what I am missing is access to that string where it says WorkflowException. I would like to have that info in an attribute/variable. 
Also I am lacking the vocabulary/term to describe that line besides "header" of the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works for Py4JJavaError but if you print error type and error you should get your "header":

```
import traceback
try:
    raise ValueError('my error')
except Exception as e:
    msg = f'Error details: \n {type(e).__name__} : {e} \n{traceback.format_exc()}'
    print(msg)
```

[image: Error without try]

[image: Error with try]